# Socket io client multiple connections from angular

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io

Is it possible to have one Angular SPA to have multiple connections to the same server. I haven't been able to find any examples.

Currently I have a working connection that I'm able to pass and recieve information from the server (socket-io v3). I use username and password to connect and there are multiple subaccounts under the main one that I would like to be able to connect to.

I'm using:

```
    "socket.io-client": "^2.5.0",
```

In angular 15